# how to solve encoding issue of text while reading from properties

Tags: java

I am developing micro services for internal use. I have propertie file with properties like

```
HEAD_ROLE_KEYS=de 1ª Linha-->Área-->Equipa-Coordenadores
```

In java, reading that property of head_role and print. But it prints like

de 1ª Linha--> Ã�rea-->Equipa-Coordenadores

So my compare operation is failed.

Kindly help me how to get exact value in java. Thanks...

NOTE: file format is UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

java expects property files to be ISO-8859-1 encoded

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to verify:

1. The editor last used to edit the property file saved the file as UTF-8.
2. Your program reads the file as UTF-8.
3. The console where the property file is printed supports UTF-8.
4. The string constant against which the property value is compared is properly encoded.